# How to count number of object based on the label using python?

Tags: python, pandas, count, statistics, row

I have a dataframe which similar like this:

```
price   type      status
2       shoes      none
3       clothes    none
6       clothes    none
3       shoes      none
4       shoes      none
6       shoes      none
2       clothes    none
3       shoes      none
6       clothes    none
8       clothes    done
```

I want to see the count of each price, based on "type" every time the status is done.
For example:
For shoes type:

```
price       count
2             1
3             2
4             1
6             1
```

so far, I have tried this:

```
g = df['status'].eq('done').iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]
df_freq = df.groupby([g, 'type']).apply(lambda x: x['price'].size().reset_index(name = "count"))
```

Unfortunately, it does not work for my data.
How can I make it using python?

Thankyou.

Comment: `df.loc[df["status"].eq("done")].groupby(["type", "price"]).count()`?

Comment: thankyou for your help anw, but it does not give me the price count based on the type

Answer (score 0):

Code that gives output as one dataframe:

```
group = df[df['status'].eq('none')].groupby('type').apply(lambda x: x.groupby('price').count())
group.columns = ['type', 'count']
grouped_df = pd.DataFrame(group['count'])
print(grouped_df)
# output
               count
type    price       
clothes 2          1
        3          1
        6          2
shoes   2          1
        3          2
        4          1
        6          1
```